# Fatal Error while Running c++ object file

Tags: c++, gcc

I have compiled C++ project using cmake utility on Red hat Linux 4.1.2.

gcc version: 4.1

When I try to run object file using following command I got an exception:

```
./GCVMP ../../dat/settlingsUnix/MPSettings.xml
exception :  Fatal Error: æ¹¥åSä
```

I am not able to understand root cause.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Probably nobody can understand a roout cause with this lack of information. But what are you trying to execute, an XML file?

Comment: Should it be `settingsUnix` rather than `settlingsUnix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the "Fatal Error:" portion is something printed by your code. It's supposed to be followed by a message explaining the error, but the message passed is corrupted, and so junk is printed.

Have you tried compiling the program with -ggdb running it under gdb? Here's a good starter on how to use the debugger: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gdb/

Comment: thnaks Nik. yes Fatal Error is printed by code. i am checking issue. Thanks for help.